# Multivariate regression in Stata

Tags: regression, self-study, stata

Given a data set of course grades, there is a female student dummy variable that is set to 1 if a student is female, and 0 if male. There is also a dummy for female instructors.

How would I perform the Hypothesis test using T-test with 5% significance, that the grades in classes taught by female instructors are higher than ones taught by male instructors, and that these differences are larger for female students? I am trying to do this in STATA. I know how Hypothesis testing works, but I don't know how to set up this problem.

Comment: That sounds like two hypotheses, and thus two tests: one for the (alternative) hypothesis that female instructors achieve better results than male instructors, and one for the (alternative) hypothesis that female students benefit more from female instructor than male students. Which hypothesis do you want to test?

Answer (score 3):

You could set this up as a multiple regression problem: see the `regress` command in Stata [note spelling]. It is not *multivariate* regression, which needs the `mvreg` command.

Attitudes to homework questions vary, but it really does not seem that you have tried anything much here to learn about Stata, even to look at the user interface or introductory documentation.