# Multivariate regression with Stata; Joint Hypothesis Testing

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, stata

There is a data set given of course grades, with the variables: high school grade and gender, for which the gender one is a dummy that is equal to 1 if female.

I am to test the joint hypothesis that there are gender differences in grades in both the intercepts and slopes of the regression model. The coefficient on the high school grade variable depends on gender.

How would I go about setting up this problem? I am doing this within STATA.

Comment: How does this differ from http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55444/multivariate-regression-in-stata

Answer (score 1):

That is what the `test` command is for, which is discussed here: http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?test